# How to append a character in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using CR version 13.0.2.000.I want to display the following Record

```
1,2,5,10,50,100
```

in the following way

```
$1
$2
$5
$10
$50
$100
```

I have tried the replace method and it successfully show the data columnwise but dont know how to append `$` sign before the starting of each element

The formula i tried is given below

```
Replace({Table7.Value},",",chrw(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you won't be able to use a formula to 'manufacture' rows; this will need to be done at the database.

If you just want to change the display, try:

```
// {@display}

Local Stringvar CRLF := Chr(10)+Chr(13);

// convert values to an array; 1,2,5,10,50,100
Stringvar Array tokens := Split({Table7.Value}, ",");

// join array
"$" + Join( tokens, CRLF + "$");
```

If you need to tally the array, try:

```
// {@aggregate}

Local Numbervar i;
Local Numbervar x;

// tally
for i := 1 to ubound(tokens) do (
  x := x + ToNumber(tokens[i]);
);

// display
x
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution. I tried by hardcoding strings and its worked for me.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Local StringVar Array x:=split({Table7.Value},",");
Local NumberVar i;
Local Stringvar y;

for i:=1 to Count(x) do
 y:=y+"$"+x[i]+",";

Replace(y,",",chrw(13))
```

Comment: I have a doubt.{Table7.Value} comes as 1,2,5,10,50,100.Then how can we get the Count(x)

Comment: Is '{Table7.Value}' is string or number

Comment: string and the value comes as 1,2,5,10,50,100 from database

Comment: It will work..implement and let me know the result... It worked for me even with database field

Comment: Im getting count(x) as 0

Comment: Do u have data in database

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors in your code and added the function `split()` on line 2 since you cannot assign a database value to an array variable. **Please double check your code before posting.** Also, why bother doing the `replace()` when you can just concatenate a chrw(13) instead of the comma in the first place?

Comment: @ryan thanks for that but I didn''t get any syntax error implemented at my end

Comment: See the edit. You had a statement that was improperly ended and an unpaired open parenthesis. The missing `split()` would not have resulted in a syntax error, it would just be incorrect.

Comment: @Ryan... Thanks for changing but without split also its working.. I have tried again today.. :)

Comment: @silva: there is no need to use `whileprintingrecords` for a formula that can be evaluated during `whilereadingrecords`.

Comment: @Craig... it worked for me with `Whileprintingrecords`...I don't think it will make any difference to end result.